# HTTP request to HTTP Cloud Function from Device(Google Cloud IoT Core)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

How can i make a "HTTP requests" to a  Google Cloud Function from a device(with CLOUD IOT CORE AUTHORIZATION)?

e.g. right now i have a device which is registered in Cloud IoT core already. In order to communicate i send the data via Pub/Sub Mqtt to the cloud function. It works well but i am not be able to send an acknowledgment message from cloud function to device that wether the response is successfull or not.

But now i would like to e.g. make a HTTP POST/GET Request to a cloud function from the device. So that this HTPP request gets a ack message e.g. "Your data has reached" back from the cloud function.

What i have tried now in my device is ..

```
def post_data(payload):
    URL='https://cloudiotdevice.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project-id}/locations/{cloud-region}/registries/{registry-id}/devices/{device-id}:publishEvent'
    payload = json.dumps(payload)
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': JWT
    }
    try:
        requests.post(URL, json=payload, headers=headers)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        logging.error('Error posting data to Cloud Function!')
    except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        logging.error('Error posting data to Cloud Function! Are Environment Variables set?')
```

But it is returning me back 400 error. I also have sub folder as a topic but i also dont know where should i define it?

payload format is like this below

```
payload = {'device': device_id,
           'type': TYPE,
           'timestamp': time.time(),
           'data': {'temperature': temperature,
                    'humidity': humidity}}
```

Comment: Can you please also explain why you have voted for a close?

Comment: Could you please be more explicit in your question as recommended in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you @JoséSoní. I updated my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a telemetry event from your device to Cloud IoT using HTTP, the payload must be JSON *and* it must be of the structure described [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiotdevice/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices/publishEvent).  Specifically, the payload of the REST POST request must be:

```
{
  "binaryData": string
}
```

Where the ACTUAL data that you want published is a base 64 encoded representation.  Looking at your example code, I'm not seeing you send a REST request with that payload.